# Yii Framework: how to set default User Roles

Tags: php, yii

I've read Yii's documentation about "role-based-access-control" but I didn't found where to configure default user roles.

I've add:

```
'authManager'=>array(
         'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
         'connectionID'=>'db',
         'defaultRoles'=>array('guest', 'authenticated', 'admin'),
),
```

to protected/config/main.php

But where I have to put these business rules?

```
$bizRule='return !Yii::app()->user->isGuest;';
$auth->createRole('authenticated', 'authenticated user', $bizRule);

$bizRule='return Yii::app()->user->isGuest;';
$auth->createRole('guest', 'guest user', $bizRule);

$bizRule='return Yii::app()->user->admin;';
$auth->createRole('admin', 'admin user', $bizRule);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: in the same place you created your roles, tasks etc / where you have `$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;`

Comment: Well the question was just that... Until now I used only the `accessRules` method inside the various controller to manage authorizations, now I want to know where to put more complex rules and use the authManager...

Comment: well you can kinda put it anywhere that makes sense, maybe make a new script (file) for it called RbacInit or something, and run using the yiic shell, or just do it all in the yiic shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this via the code you started will be a pain. Instead use the [Rights](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/) extension which was created for this job.

[Rights](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/) extension utilizes Yii's built-in Database Authorization Manager (CDbAuthManager) to provide a web interface for advanced access control.

Comment: rights is very useful and easy to use, but many often required features of rights are not documented..I tried some here..http://octathorpeweb.com/blog/2012/03/06/yii-rights-extension-rbac-role-based-access-control/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Rights seems very nice and clean but I don't want to use too many extensions in my project. Plus, since I need very basic RBAC operations I'd prefer to code it by myself, to have more control on my project :)

Comment: by too many extensions do you also refer to too many resources? Well Yii loads only those files which are need to fulfill the current request, and after your setup your system only RController and RFilter classes will be used from rights. Your system won't be slow. At least you should try out and see how well it's done. You probably end up programming 80 hours to get this setup and all kind of restrictions done.

Comment: That's a good point. I tried Rights a little bit and I think that it's a good extension but it's a little an "overkill" for my needs. Actually I simply added a "role" column to my user schema and use it to assign the user to its role everytime he log-in, using the built-in db auth manager. Should I need a more complex auth behaviour I will use Rights for sure :D